# Kivy TextInput autocompletion. How to get same result using kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to use a kv file for the TextInput in my code, but I don't know how to get the same result, how to translate this line of code:

```
text_input.bind(text=self.action)
```

someone could help me?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from textwrap import dedent

class MyApp(App):

    def action(self,instance,value):

        word_list = ["hello", "hi", "man", "girl"]

        self.root.suggestion_text = ''

        val = value[value.rfind(' ') + 1:]

        if not val:
            return
        try:
            word = [word for word in word_list
                    if word.startswith(val)][0][len(val):]
            if not word:
                return
            self.root.suggestion_text = word
        except IndexError:
            print('Index Error.')

    def build(self):
        text_input = Builder.load_string(dedent('''
            TextInput
        '''))
        text_input.bind(text=self.action)
        return text_input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind  `on_text` event with the `action` method, [using `app` keyword](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context) to refer to your `MyApp` instance (`app.action(args)`) and   the `“:”` syntax:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from textwrap import dedent


class MyApp(App):

    def action(self,instance,value):
        word_list = ["hello", "hi", "man", "girl"]
        self.root.suggestion_text = ''
        val = value[value.rfind(' ') + 1:]

        if not val:
            return
        try:
            word = [word for word in word_list
                    if word.startswith(val)][0][len(val):]
            if not word:
                return
            self.root.suggestion_text = word
        except IndexError:
            print('Index Error.')

    def build(self):
        text_input = Builder.load_string(dedent('''
            TextInput:
                on_text: app.action(self, self.text)
        '''))
        return text_input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```